# why function doesnt called?

Tags: c

I am writing the following program in C.

This program is a adjacency matrix, which asks the user to set a connection between nodes and than check to see if there is a connection between node A and node B.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

#define N 11
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

typedef int adj_mat[N][N]; /*defining adj_mat */

int path (adj_mat A, int u, int v);
```

The main function asks user to make directed graph and then asks for the user to enter two nodes to check if they exists a connection between node A and node B.

```
int main()
{
    adj_mat Matrix; /*intializing a new graph adjacency matrix. 
                     on this moment nodes are disconnected every cell contains zero */
    int dadnode, sonnode; /*intializing dad node and son node*/

    printf("Hello. Enter now the pairs of connected nodes.\n");    
    printf("enter EOF after finishing of connecting all the nodes\n");

    do {  /*here user enter the nodes to connect */
        printf("Enter the number of first node\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &dadnode);
        printf("Enter the number of second node\n");
        scanf("%d", &sonnode);

        if ((dadnode < sonnode) && (sonnode <= N) && (dadnode > 0)) /*checking if nodes are legal*/
            Matrix[dadnode][sonnode] = 1; /*if legal - connect*/
    } while ( (dadnode != EOF ) && (sonnode != EOF)); /*until user enter EOF */

    printf("Now enter u and v nodes to check if exists way from u node to we node\n");
    /*here user enter the nodes to check */
    printf("Enter the number of u node\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &dadnode);
    printf("Enter the number of v node\n");
    scanf("%d", &sonnode);

    if ((dadnode < sonnode) && (sonnode <= N) && (dadnode > 0)) /*checking if nodes are legal*/ {
        if( path(Matrix,dadnode,sonnode) == TRUE ) /*if exisits way from u to v*/
            printf ("Exists way from node u to node v ");  
    }
    else printf ("Not exists way from node u to node v ");         
}
```

The following function returns TRUE if exists way from u(dad node) to v(son node) otherwise returned FALSE

```
int path (adj_mat A, int u, int v) {
    if (v >= u) /*no sense to check if dad node yonger than son node or dad of himself */
        return FALSE; 
    int nodenum; /*number of node*/
    /* "nodenum = v - 1" because node v cannot be son of node >= v */
    for(nodenum = v - 1; nodenum > 0; nodenum-- ) {
        if (A[nodenum][v] == TRUE) /*dad detected*/
        {
            if (nodenum == u) {
                return TRUE; //complete
            } else if (path (A, u, nodenum)) {
                return TRUE; //maybe dad is a node that we are looking for (recursion)
            }
        }
    }  
    return FALSE; /*all parents of v node were cheked and noone of them isnt u node*/
}
```

Finally, I run this in gdb (ubuntu).

```
do {  /*here user enter the nodes to connect */
    printf("Enter the number of first node\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &dadnode);
    printf("Enter the number of second node\n");
    scanf("%d", &sonnode);

    if ((dadnode < sonnode) && (sonnode <= N) && (dadnode > 0)) {/*checking if nodes are legal*/
        Matrix[dadnode][sonnode] = 1; /*if legal - connect*/
    }
} while ( (dadnode != EOF ) && (sonnode != EOF)); /*until user enter EOF */
```

Why when I trying to stop this loop (from main function) by pressing Ctrl+d, the loop will continue and stop only after a pair of numbers are found where one of the numbers is -1 ?

Ok, enter "-1" and then the main function should calls the path() function to check if node a and node b are connected. If they are, then it should output a message according the result of path(Matrix,dadnode,sonnode).

However, instead of this behaviour I get the message "Program exited normally." 
Why do I get this message?

Does main function even call the path() function?
I'm not sure what the error in my code is...

Comment: ALthough I like yours `dadnode` and `sonnode` :), it is more convential to use `parentNode` and `childNode`.

Comment: *isn't. Why a function isn't called. or... Why a function doesn't get called

Answer (score 2):

`EOF` is defined as (`-1`) in `stdio.h`, however when you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to send an `EOF` message, you're sending a different character value (`4`).  The `EOF` define of (`-1`) is meant to be the return value of functions that fail due to an end-of-file or other error. So instead of comparing your input value (`dadnode` or `sonnode`) to `EOF`, you should compare the return value of `scanf()` to `EOF`.

The return value of `scanf()` is the number of items read (in your case, it should only be `1`), or `EOF` if the user sends <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Windows users will have to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>).

Example:

```
int dadnode, sonnode;
int result;

while (true)
{
    result = scanf("%d", &dadnode);
    if (result < 1) break;

    result = scanf("%d", &sonnode);
    if (result < 1) break;
}
```

Comment: while ( (scanf("%d", &sonnode) != EOF ) && (scanf("%d", &dadnode) != EOF)); ?

Comment: Yes, that line should give you what you want, although you could also use `(scanf("%d", &sonnode) == 1 )` so that the user can't enter garbage input (in which case, `scanf()` will return `0`).

Comment: after repalcing  "((dadnode != EOF ) && (sonnode != EOF)) " with      "( (scanf("%d", &sonnode) != EOF ) && (scanf("%d", &dadnode) !=EOF))"   sonnode now get 3 numbers instead 1 numbers.                      also loop didnt stop on -1.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how I would approach this situation.